# -su: bundle: command not found when starting unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I'm following a tutorial at DigitalOcean (fyi, this is the tutorials, [link1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) , [link2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) ), to install a production ready rails app using unicorn, and nginx, and when I get to the part on installing unicorn.  When I try typing this into the console:

```
sudo service unicorn_appname start
```

I get this error:

```
Starting appname
-su: bundle: command not found
```

All users can bundle.  This message makes no sense to me.  Any ideas?

Comment: `gem install bundler`?

Comment: I already did `gem install bundler` for all users...it seems to be installed if i'm not mistaken....hence the strangeness of the error message.

Comment: are you using RVM or RBENV? I see the tutorial recommends RBENV...

Comment: I think you may be onto something here, I might have installed both and mixed everything up.  I'm starting over again and be sure to use exclusively rbenv and I'll return to let everyone know what happened.

Comment: Ok, I have returned...I followed the tutorial again, to the tooth, used RBENV exclusively and I got that exact same message.  So, the RVM thing is not the issue.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://gorails.com/forum/rbenv-bundle-command-not-found)? I'm pretty sure it's your same issue, basically issues because of sudo...

Comment: Please post your app's config/unicorn_init.sh file.

Answer (score 4):

I also followed the same guide and had the same issue.

The startup script in init.d/unicorn_appname is evaluated to:

```
su - deploy -c cd /home/deploy/appname && bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

root user on startup will first su - into the rails user (in this case 'deploy') then excutes bundle to start up unicorn. rbenv is single user, only 'deploy' has bundle installed. The path to bundle is likely stored in your .bashrc file if you followed the guide. However .bashrc file which is not invoked by login in through su - and that caused the bundle not installed error.

The solution would be to include the paths related to rbenv in .profile. This way when root su - into 'deploy' the paths are loaded.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this by adding the rbenv shims path to your `.profile`

```
cd ~
vi .profile
```

look for the line that starts with PATH="
just after the quote add the following:
$HOME/.rbenv/shims:

save the file ( ESC :wq )

start the service as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you starting service with "system wide Ruby /usr/bin/ruby" which doesn't have gem "bundler" installed yet, not with version of Ruby which you expecting to be in runtime (installed through the RVM or RBENV somewhere in user namespace). Make sure desired Ruby version infrastructure is in the path prior to call "bundle exec unicorn...".

Comment: When I type bundler in the same directory, my app, it bundles...so I'm assuming bundler is installed and works in this directory though.  The same directory:  ```bundler -v
Bundler version 1.9.4
```  So how do I install bundler more than already installed?  I don't understand.

Comment: Post your service script here. (obfuscate or remove any passwords first)

Answer (score 0):

Part of my unicorn_service script:

```
USER="ubuntu"
APP_NAME="my_app_name"
APP_ROOT="/home/$USER/$APP_NAME"
ENV="production"
# environment settings
PATH="/home/$USER/.rbenv/shims:/home/$USER/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

When I ran `sudo service unicorn start` I got the same error i.e `bundle command not found`.

Initially, path was present in my `.bashrc` file.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Adding the path in `.bash_profile` did the work for me. I guess it is taking `$PATH` from `.bash_profile` not from `.bashrc`.

After copying this path to `.bash_profile` and then doing `source .bash_profile` worked for me.